# Canvas mouseover

Tags: javascript, canvas, electron

I'm having a canvas on which i have created dynamically some rectangles and when you hover over them i need to show an username that's stored, i tried to do it like this but i didn't got the result that i desired. The rectangles are not html elements so i can't use classes or ids.

This is the code that i tried:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', (evt)=>{
       mousePos = onMousePos(canvas,evt);
       for(let i=0;i<rectArray.length;i++)
           if(ctx.isPointInPath(mousePos.x,mousePos.y))
                 console.log(rectArray[i].username);
});
```

The onMousePos function checks the that the mouse is inside of an hexagon and i use the same function for mouseup, mousedown and mousemove and it works.

**EDIT** the onMousePos is this:

```
function onMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (history && timeline) {
        return {
            x: Math.round(evt.clientX - rect.left) * 1.18,
            y: Math.round(evt.clientY - rect.top) * 1.05
        };
    }
    if (timeline && history === false) {
        return {
            x: Math.round(evt.clientX - rect.left),
            y: Math.round(evt.clientY - rect.top) * 1.05
        };
    }
    if (history && timeline === false) {
        return {
            x: Math.round(evt.clientX - rect.left) * 1.18,
            y: Math.round(evt.clientY - rect.top)
        };
    }
    return {
        x: Math.round(evt.clientX - rect.left),
        y: Math.round(evt.clientY - rect.top)
    };
}
```

Comment: isPointInPath without an Path2D argument will check against the currently active subpath you have defined on your context (i.e calling it in a loop makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
   void function() {
    
    "use strict";
    
    // Classes
    
    /*
     Constructor function
     when called with new, everything attached to the 'this' keyword
     becomes a new member of the new object
    */
    function ToolTip(text) {
     this.text = text;
    }
    
    /*
     Constructor prototype, a collection
     of values & functions that are shared across all instances,
     use for constant values and member functions
    */
    ToolTip.prototype = {
     TEXT_SIZE: 15,
     TEXT_FONT: "15px Arial",
     TEXT_COLOUR: "#FFFFFFFF",
     BOX_BORDER_COLOUR: "#000000FF",
     BOX_BACKGROUND_COLOUR: "#990000FF",
     
     render: function(ctx,x,y) {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.BOX_BACKGROUND_COLOUR;
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.BOX_BORDER_COLOUR;
      ctx.font = this.TEXT_FONT;
      ctx.beginPath();
      
      ctx.rect(
       x,
       y - this.TEXT_SIZE,
       ctx.measureText(this.text).width,
       this.TEXT_SIZE
      );
      
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.fillStyle = this.TEXT_COLOUR;
      ctx.fillText(this.text,x,y - 2);
     }
    };
    
    function Rectangle(x,y,width,height,name) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     this.tooltip = new ToolTip(name);
    }
    
    Rectangle.prototype = {
     BORDER_COLOUR: "#000000FF",
     BACKGROUND_COLOR: "#0000AAFF",
     
     contains: function(x,y) {
      return x > this.x && x < this.x + this.width
       && y > this.y && y < this.y + this.height;
     },
     
     render: function(ctx) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.BORDER_COLOUR;
      ctx.fillStyle = this.BACKGROUND_COLOR;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
     }
    };
    
    // Variables
    var canvasWidth = 150;
    var canvasHeight = 150;
    var canvas = null;
    var ctx = null;
    var rectangles = null;
    
    // Functions
    function onMouseMove(e) {
     var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
     var x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
     var y = e.clientY - bounds.top;
     
     draw();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; ++i) {
      var rectangle = rectangles[i];
      
      if (rectangle.contains(x,y)) {
       rectangle.tooltip.render(ctx,x,y);
       return;
      }
     }
    }
    
    function draw() {
     ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
     
     for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; ++i) {
      rectangles[i].render(ctx);
     }
    }
    
    // Entry Point
    onload = function() {
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     canvas.width = canvasWidth;
     canvas.height = canvasHeight;
     canvas.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
     
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     
     rectangles = [
      new Rectangle(10,10,25,25,"User 1"),
      new Rectangle(45,10,25,25,"User 2"),
      new Rectangle(80,10,25,25,"User 3"),
      new Rectangle(115,10,25,25,"User 4"),
      new Rectangle(10,45,25,25,"User 5"),
      new Rectangle(45,45,25,25,"User 6"),
      new Rectangle(80,45,25,25,"User 7"),
      new Rectangle(115,45,25,25,"User 8"),
      new Rectangle(10,80,25,25,"User 9"),
      new Rectangle(45,80,25,25,"User 10"),
      new Rectangle(80,80,25,25,"User 11"),
      new Rectangle(115,80,25,25,"User 12"),
      new Rectangle(10,115,25,25,"User 13"),
      new Rectangle(45,115,25,25,"User 14"),
      new Rectangle(80,115,25,25,"User 15"),
      new Rectangle(115,115,25,25,"User 16")
     ];
     
     draw();
    }
    
   }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This example is good and this is what i want, now i have 2 mousemove events but i don't get it why the log of what i need occurs so slow it's like i have lag or something and the canvas i'm testing on has only 3 elements at the moment.